# With a precision of two decimal places, determine the average number of guns for all battleships (including the ones in the Outcomes table)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Short database description "Ships":

The database of naval ships that took part in World War II is under consideration. The database consists of the following relations: 
Classes(class, type, country, numGuns, bore, displacement) 
Ships(name, class, launched) 
Battles(name, date) 
Outcomes(ship, battle, result) 
Ships in classes all have the same general design. A class is normally assigned either the name of the first ship built according to the corresponding design, or a name that is different from any ship name in the database. The ship whose name is assigned to a class is called a lead ship.
The Classes relation includes the name of the class, type (can be either bb for a battle ship, or bc for a battle cruiser), country the ship was built in, the number of main guns, gun caliber (bore diameter in inches), and displacement (weight in tons). The Ships relation holds information about the ship name, the name of its corresponding class, and the year the ship was launched. The Battles relation contains names and dates of battles the ships participated in, and the Outcomes relation - the battle result for a given ship (may be sunk, damaged, or OK, the last value meaning the ship survived the battle unharmed). 
Notes: 1) The Outcomes relation may contain ships not present in the Ships relation. 2) A ship sunk can’t participate in later battles. 3) For historical reasons, lead ships are referred to as head ships in many exercises.

**Question:
With a precision of two decimal places, determine the average number of guns for all battleships (including the ones in the Outcomes table).**

When I'm trying to execute the following query I'm not getting error like:

> Your query returned the correct dataset on the first (available)
>   database, but it returned incorrect dataset on the second checking
>   database.

```
SELECT CAST( AVG( numGuns *1.0) AS NUMERIC(10,2)) FROM 
( 
   SELECT numguns FROM [Classes] c 
       JOIN Ships s ON c.class = s.class 
       WHERE type='bb'  
       UNION ALL 
   SELECT numguns FROM [Classes] c 
       JOIN Outcomes o ON c.class = o.ship 
       WHERE type='bb' and o.ship NOT IN(SELECT name FROM Ships) 
) t
```

Comment: It's unlikely anyone is going to read your wall of text describing the database structure - please provide something more readable to demonstrate the schema and illustrative data, like `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements, or at least a text-table with some sample data in. You might benefit from reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then trying to edit your question if you want to get decent answers.

Comment: make sure all the tables are uniquely aliased and that you use all the aliases in field selection etc

Comment: I did it. Could you please provide me the solution

Answer (score 1):

if the individual queries are valid by themselves, then I think it could be a problem with aliases, make sure all your aliases are unique and used correctly for all field names - something along theses lines, but you have to make sure the intended table is always referenced by the alias as needed

```
SELECT CAST( AVG( t.numGunsx *1.0) AS NUMERIC(10,2)) AS TheAverage FROM 
( 
   SELECT c1.numguns numgunsx FROM [Classes] c1 
       JOIN Ships s1 ON c1.class = s1.class 
       WHERE s1.type='bb'  
       UNION ALL 
   SELECT c2.numguns numgunsx FROM [Classes] c2 
       JOIN Outcomes o2 ON c2.class = o2.ship 
       WHERE c2.type='bb' and o2.ship NOT IN(SELECT sx.name FROM Ships sx) 
) t
```

Comment: Even I've tried that but still showingerror message like "Your query returned the correct dataset on the first (available) database, but it returned incorrect dataset on the second checking database.
* Data mismatch (1)"

Comment: Hi I'm trying but I'm unable to get the exact solution..Don't know where i did mistake..help me out to gain more knowledge

Answer (score 0):

```
select cast(avg(numguns*1.0) as numeric(10,2)) as Avg_numG from
(select name,ships.class,numguns from classes,ships
where ships.class=classes.class and type='bb'
UNION
select ship,ship,numguns from classes, outcomes
where classes.class= outcomes.ship and outcomes.ship not in (select name    
from ships) and type='bb'
) T
```

Please try this.